# Passing javascript functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, function

In working with some javascript I have come across behavior which is puzzling to me and I am looking for some documentation which explains what is going on.

The issue seems to be that depending upon how the functions are passed, they might be executed when I would think they are simply parameters.

Here is a simple example:

```
function f1()
{
    alert('f1');
}
function f2()
{
    alert('f2');
}
function f3(a, b)
{
    alert('f3');
}
```

Two versions of calling the above:

```
f3(f1, f2);        // shows 1 alert
f3(f1(), f2());    // shows 3 alerts
```

The first call of f3 above results in the the f1 and f2 functions not being called and you get one alert for "f3". The second call of f3 functions being called, so you get three alerts for "f1", "f2", and "f3".

In actual code I will be using the first version so that f3 can decide if it wants to call f1 and f2. It took me a bit of fiddling to get it right.

I did not expect this behavior and thought that either with or without the parenthesis the f1 and f2 would not be called just by having them be parameters.

Again, I am looking for some documentation that explains how this works.

Comment: The documentation you need to know is that `()` calls a function, otherwise you're just referencing a function. Your first line passes references of the `f1` and `f2` functions, to `f3`. Your second line immediately calls `f1` and `f2`, and passes their return values (which are `undefined`, because they don't return anything) to `f3`. Since `f3` does nothing with `a` and `b`, it doesn't matter what you pass

Comment: if you call them, you pass the return of the function as the parameter, not the function itself. since the arguments are resolved before passing, js has no idea of what actually happened in the call. In your case, all functions return undefined, but since you never use arguments, all that doesn't matter.

Comment: Some languages  have the ability to defer a function call. JavaScript has no such ability. When you call it, it's called immediately.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'm not trying to argue; I'm just wondering - what languages are you talking about?

Comment: @Ian: :-) The `Go` language is one example... perhaps there are others. In Go, you can do `defer foo("bar")`, and the argument will be resolved immediately at the time of the call, but the actual call won't happen until after the `return` statement of the function you're in. Very handy for situations where you *must* call some function before returning.

Comment: ...to be clear, Go doesn't automatically defer calls in the argument position of another call. Didn't want to give that false impression.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Very cool, never looked into that language before, thanks :)

Comment: @Ian: You're welcome. I don't know what other languages you know, but if you're like I was, looking for a lower-level, compiled language with nice support for concurrency and multiple threads, then I'd suggest giving Go a try. It was really pretty easy to pick up coming from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second line:

```
f3(f1(), f2());
```

Your are not *passing* `f1` and `f2`, you are *calling* them, and passing their (undefined) return values to `f3`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, adding () to a function, even when passing as a parameter will invoke the function immediately. Example of setting a timeout:

```
function doStuff() {
    alert("ok");
}

setTimeout(doStuff(), 300);
```

You will be alerted `ok` immediately because the function is invoked immediately. Setting the timeout with:

```
setTimeout(doStuff, 300);
```

Will only alert now when the timeout is called, because you are passing the function in correctly as a parameter.

You will commonly see functions passed in as parameters like this in AJAX callback functions.

The documentation for `setTimeout` has a great section on callback functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

(Yes I realize `setTimeout` was not used in the question, but I felt this example helped answer the question nicely)

Answer (score 0):

You logic is puzzling. You are passing parameters you never user but let's roll 
with the punches.

Your question regards the number of alarms; 
You are passing parameters to function that never uses them and you invoke it. 
so what actually happens is:

```
function f3(a, b)
{
console.log("argument 1: " + arguments[0]); //Access the arguments fed to the function
console.log("argument 2: " + arguments[1]); 
    alert('f3');
}
*
```

`f3(f1, f2);`
Pops alert "f3"*

```
and logs:
argument 1: function f1()
{
    alert('f1');
}
argument 2: function f2()
{
    alert('f2');
}
```

`f3(f1(),f2())`

*pops all the alerts*
and logs:

```
argument 1 undefined
argument 2 undefined
```

Comment: Never using those functions because this is a toy example stripped of all extranous functionality. Of course in the real code, those function have a purpose and are used.

Answer (score 0):

When a function has parameters its very clear that parenthesis are used to immediately call it

```
function sum(a, b){
    return a + b;
}

console.log( sum(1, 2) ); //prints 3
```

The `f()` version is just a special case of this where your parameter list is empty.